# Error Undefined Procedure in Prolog while using (condition -> then_clause ; else_clause)

Tags: eclipse, prolog

I was told that such a syntax (condition -> then_clause; else_clause) permits to a if(...)do(...)else(...).

```
:- lib(fd).

ifs(sel).
ifm(moutarde).
ifld(lesdeux).

ifrien(A) :-
   A#\=sel,
   A#\=moutarde,
   A#\=lesdeux.


selmoutarde(Vars) :-
   Vars = [B, C, D, M],
   Vars :: [sel, moutarde, lesdeux],

   ( not(ifld(C)) ->
      B#=sel
   ;
      true
   ),
   ( ( not(ifs(D)) /\ ifm(D) /\ ifld(D) \/ ifld(M) ) /\ ifs(B) ->
      B#=lesdeux
   ;
      true
   ),
   ( ( not(ifs(D)) /\ ifm(D) /\ ifld(D) \/ ifld(M)) /\ ifrien(B) ->
      B#=moutarde
   ;
      true
   ).
```

I get the following error when running it with `selmoutarde(V)`:

```
Calling an undefined procedure (not ifs(_485)) /\ ifm(_485) /\ ifld(_485) \/ ifld(_502) /\ ifs(_451) in module eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think is wrong is that you should place another pair of brackets around the statement. I'm not 100% sure though.
But instead of `if -> do ; else,` doing the following might work: `(if) -> (do) ; (else).`

(I'm assuming the code for `Vars` is 100% correct, as I do not know what happens there. So if the following things I say are wrong, I apologise in advance.)

Second, doesn't this code `not(ifs(D)) /\ ifm(D) /\ ifld(D)` always fail. `D` cannot be both `moutarde` and `lesdeux` at the same time can it?

Same with the second and third if statements. You first make sure `B` is `sel` or nothing from the list and then as the *do* make sure `B` is `lesdeux` or `moutarde` respectively.

---

Anyway, if I'm wrong, why is it necessary to create a separate predicate for each of the items? Wouldn't the following also work?

```
ifrien(X) :-
   \+ member(B, [sel, moutarde, lesdeux]).

selmoutarde(Vars) :-
   Vars = [B, C, D, M],
   Vars :: [sel, moutarde, lesdeux],

   ( (C \= lesdeux) ->
      B #= sel
   ;
      true
   ),
   ( ( (D \= sel /\ D = moutarde /\ D = lesdeux \/ M = lesdeux) /\ B = sel) ->
      B #= lesdeux
   ;
      true
   ),
   ( ( (D \= sel /\ D = moutarde /\ D = lesdeux \/ M = lesdeux) /\ ifrien(B) ) ->
      B #= moutarde
   ;
      true
   ).
```